# How to group by in Panda with multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-science, pandas-groupby

Consider a Panda DataFrame as below

```
Fruit   Rate    Quantity
-------------------------
Apple   2       4
Apple   3       3
Apple   5       9
Mango   4       5
Mango   6       12
Banana  2       2
banana  1       2
```

Here the total quantity  of fruits.

Mango: 5+12=17

Apple:  4+3+9= 16

Banana: 2+2=4

What i want is a new dataframe which is sorted(descending) by the total quantity(irrespective of rate) of each Fruit and then each fruit by its rate.

For better understanding see desired output as below

```
Fruit   Rate    Quantity
---------------------------
Mango   6       12
Mango   4       5
Apple   5       9
Apple   3       3
Apple   2       4
Banana  2       2
Banana  1       2
```

Explanation: Since mango has highest quantity ie, 17 (then Apple with 16 then Banana with 4) all the rows of mango are placed on top followed by Apple anfd then with Banana. Also there are 2 rows of mango with rate 4 and 6. So Mango of rate 6 will be placed higher than mango of rate 4 in the output.

Can someone provide me with the Panda code?

Many Thanks

BTW, I am able to do that by sql

```
select fr_table.*
from fr_table,
( select fruit, sum(quantity) sm
  from fr_table
  group by fruit
 ) temp
 where 
 fr_table.fruit=temp.fruit
 order by temp.sm desc, fr_table.rate desc;
```

Comment: Apparently you want to sort not group your table. Take a look at [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: Hi PeterE,
Any code will be very helpfull. Thanks.
I couldn't figure out the Panada code.
And i want all the rows sorted by rate also.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. Add a `Total` column, sort by `Total` and `Rate`, then drop `Total`.

Note `.sort` has now been depreciated in favour of `.sort_values`, but since you are on Python 2.7 your Pandas version might accept `.sort`.

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby('Fruit')['Quantity'].transform('sum')

df = df.sort(columns=['Total', 'Rate'], ascending=False, axis=0)\
       .drop('Total', 1)
```

Result:

```
    Fruit  Rate  Quantity
4   Mango     6        12
3   Mango     4         5
2   Apple     5         9
1   Apple     3         3
0   Apple     2         4
5  Banana     2         2
6  Banana     1         2
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked . You just helped me in solving a data science problem.
One question- 

df['Total'] = df.groupby('Fruit')['Quantity'].transform('sum')

In this why 'fruit'  is written inside () and Quantity inside [].

Since we are grouping  by Fruit and quantity,can't we write as

df['Total'] = df.groupby[ 'Fruit', 'Quantity'].transform('sum')

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are a SQL person, don't fight it, use SQL to pivot the Pandas Data Frame via ['pandasql'](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandasql)

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df = pd.DataFrame([['Apple',2,4],
['Apple',3,3],
['Apple',5,9],
['Mango',4,5],
['Mango',6,12],
['Banana',2,2],
['banana',1,2]], columns=
['Fruit',   'Rate',   'Quantity'])

q1 = """
select df.*
from df,
( select fruit, sum(quantity) sm
  from df
  group by fruit
 ) temp
 where 
 df.fruit=temp.fruit
 order by temp.sm desc, df.rate desc;"""

newdf = ps.sqldf(q1, locals())

print(newdf)
```

Result:

```
    Fruit  Rate  Quantity
0   Mango     6        12
1   Mango     4         5
2   Apple     5         9
3   Apple     3         3
4   Apple     2         4
5  Banana     2         2
6  banana     1         2
```

**EDIT**

From timing the code, JPP's, pandas only, answer is much more efficient, it is not surprising considering the overhead.

```
import timeit
from sklearn.utils import resample

df5mil = resample(df , n_samples=5000, random_state=0)
q2 = """
select df5mil.*
from df5mil,
( select fruit, sum(quantity) sm
  from df5mil
  group by fruit
 ) temp
 where 
 df5mil.fruit=temp.fruit
 order by temp.sm desc, df5mil.rate desc;"""

def performance_test(df):
    df['Total'] = df.groupby('Fruit')['Quantity'].transform('sum')
    return df.sort_values(by=['Total', 'Rate'], ascending=False, axis=0)\
        .drop('Total', 1)
```

Timing the result:

```
timeit.timeit('newdf5mil = ps.sqldf(q2, locals())', number=10, setup = 'from __main__ import df5mil',globals=globals())
Out[21]: 1.3951236820267923

timeit.timeit('newdf5mil = performance_test(df5mil)', number=10, setup = 'from __main__ import df5mil',globals=globals())
Out[22]: 0.12005714190763683
```

...but you don't get to use SQL.

Comment: @ AChervony - Thanks for pointing that out. I am looking forward to it.
But will there be any issue related to speed. I mean which will be faster when query involves large data set say, 5 million records pandas dataframe query or pandasql

Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, there will be speed related issues.I  felt it slow down even with 5K.